# Apply jquery plugin to dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I store all javascript code which deals frontend part of app in frontend.js.
If dom element does not exist on this page but i try apply plugin javascript throw error
Sample:

```
$('#normalImage').Jcrop({
    setSelect:[ 0, 0, 48, 48 ],
    sideHandles:false,
    onChange:showPreview,
    onSelect:showPreview,
    aspectRatio:1
});
```

I found one solution for this problem it's check size

```
if($('#normalImage').size() > 0)
//apply plugin
```

But i'm not sure what is right way

Comment: do you mean `doesn't exist` **yet**? you could wrap your code in a `$(docuemnt).ready()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably dealing with a bad plugin as it's the plugins job to not throw an error when the jquery selector is empty. But in this case checking the size or length is the correct way for it to work.

Best use this:

```
var dom = $('#normalImage');
if(dom.length > 0) 
{
   dom.Jcrop({
      setSelect:[ 0, 0, 48, 48 ],
      sideHandles:false,
      onChange:showPreview,
      onSelect:showPreview,
      aspectRatio:1
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the right way to check the .length and comapring it with zero to check if the collection has any element or not?

From jquery site:

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#myelement").length > 0){
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: `if ($("#myelement").length)` would be enough even though your solution might be easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a dom element exists you could use:

```
if ( $("#normalImage").length > 0 ) {
  //do something
}
```